# c# UWP - Convert byte array to InMemoryRandomAccessStream/IRandomAccessStream

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a problem converting byte array to `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` or `IRandomAccessStream` in windows 8?

This is my code, but It doesn't work :

```cs
internal static async Task<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> ConvertTo(byte[] arr) 
{
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    
    Stream stream = randomAccessStream.AsStream();
    
    await stream.WriteAsync(arr, 0, arr.Length);
    await stream.FlushAsync();

    return randomAccessStream;
}
```

And I created the `RandomAccessStreamReference` and set the requst datapack in order to share the image to other app

```cs
private static async void OnDeferredImageStreamRequestedHandler(DataProviderRequest Request) 
{
    DataProviderDeferral deferral = Request.GetDeferral();
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = await ConvertTo(arr);
    
    RandomAccessStreamReference referenceStream =
            RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(stream);
    
    Request.SetData(referenceStream);
}
```

There's no exception but I can't use the result image byte array

I think there's an error when converting `byte[]` to `InMemoryRandomAccessStream`, but it doesn't throw an exception.

Anybody know how to implement it?

if anyone knows how to convert the byte array to `IRandomAccessStream`, it's also appreciated

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Please check [this](http://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-irandomaccessstream/) & tell me if you can solve the issue.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add the `using` statement at the top of the document.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
internal static async Task<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> ConvertTo(byte[] arr)
{
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await randomAccessStream.WriteAsync(arr.AsBuffer());
    randomAccessStream.Seek(0); // Just to be sure.
                    // I don't think you need to flush here, but if it doesn't work, give it a try.
    return randomAccessStream;
}
```

Answer (score 27):

On Windows 8.1 it's even easier as we added the AsRandomAccessStream extension method:

```
internal static IRandomAccessStream ConvertTo(byte[] arr)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(arr);
    return stream.AsRandomAccessStream();
}
```

Comment: This seems not to work for some scenarios, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332217/unauthorizedaccessexception-using-asrandomaccessstream

Answer (score 6):

In one line:

```
internal static IRandomAccessStream ConvertTo(byte[] arr)
{
    return arr.AsBuffer().AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream();
}
```

Comment: It looks like an action that copies the data three times. You need to check that this is not happening in order for the answer to be usable.