# UnauthorizedAccessException using AsRandomAccessStream

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I just upgraded my project from Win 8 to Win 8.1 and I'm trying to take advantage of some of the new features in the SDK. One of those is the new `AsRandomAccessStream` extension method. The problem I'm having is when I use it, I'm getting an Unauthorized Access Exception.

> Exception:Caught: "MemoryStream's internal buffer cannot be accessed."
>   (System.UnauthorizedAccessException) A
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException was caught: "MemoryStream's
>   internal buffer cannot be accessed." Time: 3/11/2014 10:23:11 AM
>   Thread:[4308]

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
var imageStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes as byte[]); 
image.SetSource(imageStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
```

- imageBytes is a valid byte[]
- imageStream is a valid MemoryStream
- imageStream.Position = 0

any thoughts?

Comment: Do you need that call? MemoryStream should already handle random access just fine. Try taking it out, ie. pass in just `imageStream`.

Comment: This does not work because `SetSource` requires an object implementing `IRandomAccessStream` which `MemoryStream` does not implement.

Comment: Perhaps this will give you what you need? http://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-irandomaccessstream/

Comment: I have a workaround in place from Win 8, but I'm curious why the new extension method introduced in the 8.1 SDK is throwing an exception for me.

Comment: What was the solution? :)

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this problem today and to me, it appears as an API bug/inconsistency.

In .NET 4, calls to MemoryStream.GetBuffer() require the usage of certain constructors (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx). More specifically, the buffer of the MemoryStream must be marked as exposable.

Now, AsRandomAccessStream() calls MemoryStream.GetBuffer(). However, in Win8.1, the constructor for setting the expose-ability of a MemoryStream is missing. Therefore, when you create the MemoryStream, use the default empty constructor and then call Write().

Thus, I think this should work.

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
imageStream.Write(yourdata, 0, yourdata.Length); 
image.SetSource(imageStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
```

Comment: Thank you.  This should be accepted as the answer.  It is an excellent answer.

Comment: This should definitively be the accepted answer, after one hour of trying to figure out why wasn't the stream visible, initializing using the default empty constructor fixed it. Just a small note: After you're done writing set the position back to 0 otherwise it won't be always use'able.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is to combine some extension methods.

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
var imageSource = imageBytes.AsBuffer().AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream();
image.SetSource(imageSource);
```